# how to refresh my dropdown based on another dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have two dropdowns like customer and company.my customer drop down having list of customers .Based on select of customer, I have to populate the company.I am getting the company details from backend as a JSON String Object.

first time  when I select customer it displaying the that  perticular customer related company information.

My Problem is 
seconed time, I select another customer(on change) but its displaying old customer company details and present selected customer company details. I want only present customer data on my company drop down.

This is my code.
On selection of customer I am getting result(company name list).

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function getcompanyNames(result){
    var data = JSON.parse(result);
    $.each(data, function(key, value)
    {
        $("#companydetails").append("<option>" + value.environments_name  + "</option>");
    });

}
```

My drop down has these options.

```
hcl - dev
ibm -  test
infosys -pro
ibm-pro
ec- -test
```

My requirement is if my option contains the pro then give first priority for that options .and dev is second priority and test is 3rd priority.

How to set priority for my option..

Comment: Have you checked which value is being passed as a parameter? Because I suspect when you call second time onChange, it is passing first time selected value only. So you need to make sure that you pass currently selected value only. Can you show your javascript code of onChange event?

Answer (score 0):

Before populating new data make sure you clear your dropdown.

[empty() | jquery referrence](https://api.jquery.com/empty/)

```
$( "#companydetails" ).empty();
```

Comment: @mvswetha do not forget to accepted answer, that helps you to resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function getcompanyNames(result){
    var data = JSON.parse(result);
    $("#companydetails").html('');
    $.each(data, function(key, value)
    {
        $("#companydetails").append("<option>" + value.environments_name  + "</option>");
    });
    $("#companydetails").selectmenu("refresh", true);
}
```

Comment: How to set the priority for my drop down options.

Comment: Priority will be taken in the order which you have added.

Comment: how to add customized priority for my option data.above i mentioned my dropdown values and priority, can you tell me clearly

Comment: I hope I may not understand your priority thing if the above statement not satisfies you.

Answer (score 0):

$("#").append('...'); will append new companies list along with your old data. On Selecting another customer you should clear old list then append new list.

Use below code.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function getcompanyNames(result){
var data = JSON.parse(result);
$("#companydetails").html('');
$.each(data, function(key, value)
{
    $("#companydetails").append("<option>" + value.environments_name  + "</option>");
});
}
```

If you are looking for sorting based on your option value text so you can use something like below. since your sorting is based on text and also not in alphabetical order so this is an alternate for you.

```
var data = JSON.parse(result);
var sortedData = $.merge([], $.grep(data, function (item) { return item.environments_name.toLowerCase().indexOf("pro") > -1; }));
sortedData = $.merge(sortedData, $.grep(data, function (item) { return item.environments_name.toLowerCase().indexOf("dev") > -1; }));
sortedData = $.merge(sortedData, $.grep(data, function (item) { return item.environments_name.toLowerCase().indexOf("test") > -1; }));
$("#companydetails").html('');
$.each(sortedData , function(key, value)
{
    $("#companydetails").append("<option>" + value.environments_name  + "</option>");
});
```

Comment: How to set the priority for my drop down options.

Comment: If you are looking for sorting then go with above code.