# Upon append values stay in place

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am generating options into a select via AJAX. those options getting appeneded upon a selection of anohter select.

The first function which contains the append data:

```
    var appendto_c = function(appendto, value, curcode) {
    appendto.append("<option value=\"" + value.currency_value + "\">" + value.type + " " + curcode + value.currency_value + "</option>"); //set the option
    $(".currency_val").find(".select2-chosen").html(value.type + " " + curcode + value.currency_value); //set the placeholder
}
```

The second function does the ajax and appends into the select depending on the currency id it will get from the main dropdown:

```
var showcurval = function(cur_code) {
    var $options = $('.currency_v'); // the optgroup append to
    var $curcode = '';
    $.ajax({
       type: 'GET',
       url:  '/transactions/get_currency_val?cur_code=' + cur_code,
       success: function(data) {
           var obj = JSON.parse(data);
           $.each(obj, function (k, v) {
               switch (v.currency_code) {
                   case '47':
                       $curcode = '€';
                       appendto_c($options, v, $curcode);
                       break;
                   case '33':
                       $curcode = 'Kč';
                       appendto_c($options, v, $curcode);
                       break;
                   case '131':
                       $curcode = '₽';
                       appendto_c($options, v, $curcode);
                       break;
                   case '144':
                       $curcode = '$';
                       appendto_c($options, v, $curcode);
                       break;
                   case '168':
                       alert('Please set a currency!');
                       break;
               }
           });
       }
    });
}
```

The final function incharge for sending the currency code to showcurval..

```
 var selectcurrency = function() {

    var $currency = $(".currency_input").select2(); // main input
    var $curval  = $('.currency_val').select2(); // secondary select with our values
    var $options = $('.currency_v'); // the optgroup append to

    $currency.on('change', function(e) {
       showcurval($(this).select2('data').id);
    });
}
selectcurrency();
```

JSON:

```
[{"currency_value":"26.98","currency_code":"47","type":"BUY"},{"currency_value":"25.98","currency_code":"47","type":"SELL"}]
```

Now upon each change of the `selectcurrency();` the options getting appended however, chosing other currency the old one stay. i tried to use html instead of append but then only 1 option appears in the select.. Suggestions?

Comment: You should provide a jsFiddle to get faster answer. What you basically need is to keep track of currency added and replace it while appending new one or use a regex replacing all currencies before appending new one. As a side not, you could surely just use a pseudo element to display currency instead, and set its content to relevant currency. I don't know that much select2 plugin but i guess it would be possible/easier.

Answer (score 0):

You should empty the $options before appending the values.

```
var showcurval = function(cur_code) {
    var $options = $('.currency_v'); // the optgroup append to
    var $curcode = '';
    $.ajax({
       type: 'GET',
       url:  '/transactions/get_currency_val?cur_code=' + cur_code,
       success: function(data) {
           var obj = JSON.parse(data);
           $options.html("");
           $.each(obj, function (k, v) {
               switch (v.currency_code) {
                   case '47':
                       $curcode = '€';
                       appendto_c($options, v, $curcode);
                       break;
                   case '33':
                       $curcode = 'Kč';
                       appendto_c($options, v, $curcode);
                       break;
                   case '131':
                       $curcode = '₽';
                       appendto_c($options, v, $curcode);
                       break;
                   case '144':
                       $curcode = '$';
                       appendto_c($options, v, $curcode);
                       break;
                   case '168':
                       alert('Please set a currency!');
                       break;
               }
           });
       }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your ajax success, before $.each try to clean your old option list by using

```
$("select").html('');
```

For more details refer below example:
[example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33865414/how-to-refresh-my-dropdown-based-on-another-dropdown/33865642#33865642)

Comment: As i understand it, OP needs to keep old values